# C Analog To STL

Tags: c, stl

Just because I'm curious--is there any C analog to the functionality of the STL in C++?  I've seen mention of a [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org) library called glib that a few people consider fills the bill but are there other libraries that would provide STL functionality in C?

Comment: Why? 99% of the time you can convert well written C code to C++ code by just changing the compiler setting. Why not start using C++ code?

Comment: @davr, I am using C++ code.  I was just curious about the possibility of something like the STL (and its data structures) in C.  I keep telling people using C++ to stop using arrays--use <vector> instead.  So I was curious if there were something safer in C.

Comment: @davr  This question is quite useful for people who write code for embedded systems that only offer C compilers. If we can do C++ style programming in C, we can have C++ functionality on a huge variety of embedded processors.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, `glib` is a pretty good choice: it includes a lot of utilities for manipulating containers like linked lists, arrays, hash tables, etc.  And there is also an object-oriented framework called `GObject` that you can use to make objects with signals and slots in C (albeit with rather verbose function call names like `gobject_set_property`, since C doesn't have any syntax for objects).  And there is also code for main loops so you can write event-driven programs.

For more info see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib

Glib was originally part of GTK, but the non-GUI code has been completely factored out so that you can use it in command-line programs: http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/

Answer (score 4):

[CLIB](http://clibutils.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Adding another option (full disclosure, I am the author); if you can compile and link C++, you can have a look into `libcdada`, which has a pure C API, but uses `libstdc++` as a backend for most of the containers:

https://github.com/msune/libcdada

Answer (score 2):

Well since STL's very nature is based on templates which C doesn't have, it would be difficult to even come close to the STL in C.  The best you could hope for is some collection classes which manipulate void* pointers to unknown object.

Comment: @James Curran, I was asking for an _analog_ to the STL.  I realize that templates are a C++ feature.

Comment: STL is more than just a container library.

Comment: I'm aware that STL is more than a container library, which is why I said "The best you could hope for"

Comment: @Onorio: Templates are at the very essence of the STL.  Your question is much like say "I need something like an airplane, but don't worry about the flying part"

Comment: @James Curran:  So maybe he's looking for a car, bus, train or boat.

Comment: @Mike: Then he would need to clarify what non-flying parts of a plane he wants.

Comment: @James Curran: Am I mistaken in thinking that there were STL-like structures in C# before the introduction of generics into that language?  What about Java--didn't that have data structures analogous to STL before they added generics to that language?  Why would a C STL be such a conceptual stretch?

Comment: Prior to the introduction of generic, C# has ArrayList and a few like that, basically, "some collection classes which manipulate void* pointers to unknown object." as I said in my answer.  But the STL is far more than that.  The affect of LINQ's Enumerable class (in .net) begins to approach STL.

Comment: Generic containers could be implemented in C in a more-or-less type-safe way.  You could store the actual data as anonymous memory, but store a hash of the type name (this can be calculated using a C macro) in the container structure and provide macros to access the data which would check the type and cast the anonymous memory to the type.  Iterators could be done using C-style interfaces (implemented as structures of function pointers, one structure per container type), which are actually quite clean to code and use.