# Standard Library for C

Tags: c++, c, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Analog To STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201413/c-analog-to-stl)

Is there something like STL for C.

Comment: Many duplicates on SO already, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201413/c-analog-to-stl

Comment: Well, see, I had the correct answer :)

Comment: ....if you want the STL, why not write C++ and be done with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at the [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/), which provides lots of interesting features

Answer (score 0):

well there is the C library of course :)

but I do not see the use of templates for C

Answer (score 0):

There's not really anything *quite* like the STL; but there *are* a lot of libraries. glib has been mentioned, but usually it's not always useable together with whatever libraries you are using for actually achieving what you want to do.