# Iterate through a List and print items

Tags: c, list

I have a list like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListItem 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct ListItem *next;
};

int main()
{   
    int x1 =0; 
    int y1 = 0;

    printf("Please enter the x coordinate: ");
    scanf("%d", &x1); 
    printf("Please enter the y coordinate: ");
    scanf("%d", &y1); 

    struct ListItem root;
    if( root.next == NULL )
    {
        root.x = x1;
        root.y = y1;
        //I dont know what should I assign here but I want to have about 30 locations
        //root.next = struct ListItem next;
    }


    //WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?
    {
        printf("Your location is : (%d,%d)\n", root.x, root.y); 
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a loop to iterate through it so that I can print every element on the list :)
Basically what I am trying to do is, I want to get the locations from the user and then I will print them.
Please help .

Comment: Thats going to be painful. Any reason for using C for this? Any reason you can't just use an array?

Comment: It wasn't very painful, may be 20 mins to write and test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked list. Input coordinates until you enter zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListItem
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct ListItem *next;
};

int main()
{
    int x1 =0;
    int y1 = 0;
    int iCount = 0; // keep count of the structures allocated
    int iEach = 0;
    struct ListItem root = { 0, 0, NULL};// declare and initialize the first structure
    struct ListItem* pFreeListItem = NULL;// declare a pointer and initialize it null. use for freeing memory later
    struct ListItem* pListItem = &root;// declare a pointer and initialize it to point to the first structure

    while ( 1) { // the main loop

        printf("Please enter the x coordinate: ");
        scanf(" %d", &x1);
        printf("Please enter the y coordinate: ");
        scanf(" %d", &y1);

        pListItem->x = x1; // use the pointer to assign the coordinate
        pListItem->y = y1;

        iCount++; // keep track of the number of structures
        printf("Input complete for location number %d\n", iCount);


        printf("Enter 0 to exit or any other number to continue: ");
        scanf(" %d", &y1);
        if ( y1 == 0) { // exit the loop if zero is entered
            break;
        }
        else { // if zero was not entered
            pListItem->next = malloc ( sizeof ( struct ListItem));// allocate memory for the next structure
            if ( pListItem->next == NULL) {
                //allocation failed
                exit (1);
            }

            pListItem = pListItem->next; // set the pointer to point to the new 'next' structure
            pListItem->next = NULL; // set this to null as no memory has yet been allocated
        }
    }

    pListItem = &root; // set the pointer to the original structure root
    for ( iEach = 0; iEach < iCount; iEach++) // loop through each structure. icount holds the number of structures
    {
        printf("Location number %d is : (%d,%d)\n", iEach + 1, pListItem->x, pListItem->y);
        pListItem = pListItem->next; // set the pointer to the next structure

    }

    pListItem = root.next; // set the pointer to the first allocated structure
    for ( iEach = 1; iEach < iCount; iEach++) // loop through each structure
    //start with 1 as the first structure was not allocate and does not need to be freed. icount holds the number of structures
    {
        pFreeListItem = pListItem->next; // set the free pointer to the next structure
        free ( pListItem); // free the memory for the structure
        pListItem = pFreeListItem; // point to the free pointer
    }
}
```

EDIT: this code will show the address of the pointers and maybe that will help clarify what is going on

```
        else { // if zero was not entered
            pListItem->next = malloc ( sizeof ( struct ListItem));// allocate memory for the next structure
            if ( pListItem->next == NULL) {
                //allocation failed
                exit (1);
            }
            printf ( "pListItem points to %p and pListItem->next points to %p\n", pListItem, pListItem->next);
            pListItem = pListItem->next; // set the pointer to point to the new 'next' structure
            pListItem->next = NULL; // set this to null as no memory has yet been allocated
            printf ( "NOW pListItem points to %p and pListItem->next points to %p\n", pListItem, pListItem->next);
        }
```

Comment: Oh wow :)

This just was amazing :O
 
pListItem = pListItem->next; // set the pointer to point to the new 'next' structure


pListItem->next = NULL; // set this to null as no memory has yet been allocated


Could you tell me what are you doing in theses lines?

Comment: What if I want the x coordinate to be a string, 
That is it is x[31] @user3121023

Answer (score 1):

Here's a toy program that works, demonstrating a list stored in an array.
Actually compiles with no warnings -  gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 l.c

The dynamically allocated version using calloc, works to, if you want dynamic memory, so you can add to the list later.

```
ladm@ash:~/src/scratch> ./a.out|head | sed 's/^/    /'
array[ 0] : (1,1)
array[ 1] : (2,2)
array[ 2] : (3,3)
Your location is : (3,3)
Your location is : (2,2)
Your location is : (1,1)
array[ 2] : (3,3)
array[ 1] : (2,2)
array[ 0] : (1,1)

ladm@ash:~/src/scratch> cat l.c | sed 's/^/    /'
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct ListItem
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct ListItem *next;
} ListItem;

void getCoord(int *x, int *y) {
    static int num = 1;
    *x = *y = num++;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv) {

    const int N = 3;
    ListItem listN[ N];
    /* ListItem *listN = calloc( N, sizeof( ListItem));   */  /* Dynamic allocation method */

    /* First Coordinate */
    listN[ 0].next = NULL;                     /* Add item at front of list */
    getCoord( &listN[ 0].x, &listN[ 0].y);            /* Does the scanf stuff */

    /* Add new coords to the list */
    for (int i=1; i < N; i++) {
         getCoord( &listN[ i].x, &listN[ i].y);            /* Does the scanf stuff */

         listN[ i].next = &listN[ i-1];                     /* Add item at front of list */
    }

    /* List built */
    {
    ListItem *first = &listN[ N-1];

    /* Dump all the coords in backing store */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("array[ %d] : (%d,%d)\n", i, listN[ i].x, listN[ i].y);
    }

    /* Print list following pointers - should be reversed */
    for (ListItem *l = first; l != NULL; l = l->next) {
        printf("Your location is : (%d,%d)\n", l->x, l->y);
    }
    /* Dump all the coords in backing store reversed */
    for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("array[ %d] : (%d,%d)\n", i, listN[ i].x, listN[ i].y);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of locations you will have, you better use an array or matrix, like:

int x[30];
int y[30];

or

int location[60];

or

int location[2][30];

And use a for loop to iterate over the elements.

If you don't know the number of locations, then you wish to search for LinkedList (or ArrayList) implementation in C. There are plenty of material on Internet teaching how to use those data structures.

Comment: But if you want to try out a linked list exercise, you don't want to use an array.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to iterate through a list would be making functions like `give_successor` and `is_after_last`, then using it in a `for` loop, like that:

```
struct ListItem *l;
struct ListItem *head;
for (l = head; !(is_after_last(l)); l = give_successor(l)) {
    do_stuff(l);
}
```

Implementation of `is_after_last` may vary depending on implementation of the list: you might want to check if `l == NULL` or if `l` points to artificial element at the end of the list.
Function `give_successor` looks like that:

```
struct ListItem *give_successor(l) {
    if (l == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return l->next
}
```

However, I recommend using tables and libraries like [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201413/c-analog-to-stl).

Comment: Making lists encapsulated would be a good exercise at some point, but the OP is probably playing with lists, to get feel for pointers, so just testing things like `l == NULL` and using `l = l->next` is probably better.  Finding an element in a list.. you can't write good encapsulation functions until you have an idea how you'ld use the lists.